# Documentation for @UiHandler

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

I started to look into using GWT in combination with UiBuilder. I'm a bit puzzled about how you can use the `@UiHandler(..)` directive to make simple event handle code as written down in the [GWT documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Simple_binding):

```
@UiHandler("button")
void handleClick(ClickEvent e) {
  Window.alert("Hello, AJAX");
}
```

In this case the method `handleClick` is used.
How do you know for each GWT widget what methods can be created with `@UiHandler`? For some you can also create a `doClose()` method.

But what can you use with, for instance, a `ListBox` to get an event an item is selected? Where in the documentation can I see this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The parameter you pass to the `@UiHandler` annotation is the name of the appropriate field you want to assign that `*Handler`. So, in this case you are assigning a `ClickHandler` to a `Button button` (actually, we just know the field's name).

As for how this exactly works - it's part of GWT magic :) My guess is that, just like any other UiBinder related code (I think there was a presentation on Google IO, that showed the code that UiBinder generates), at compilation time the compiler figures out what goes where. In this example: we have a `Button button`, and we have a `@UiHandler` annotated method that has a `ClickEvent` parameter -> that *must* mean it's a `ClickHandler` (notice that the method's name *doesn't* matter). So let's add some code at compile time (in the constructor, probably) that adds that handler to the button. If you are interested in a more comprehensive answer - check out the source :D

> But what can you use with, for
>   instance, a `ListBox` to get an event
>   an item is selected? Where in the
>   documentation can I see this?

In the [GWT API reference](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/index.html). In this case, you are probably looking for [ListBox.addChangeHandler](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ListBox.html#addChangeHandler(com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ChangeHandler)). But you usually won't find `@UiHandler` related code there - that's because it would be redundant - you always construct the `@UiHandler` methods the same way:

1. You check the `*Handler` that you want to add, say [`ChangeHandler`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/ChangeHandler.html)
2. It has a `void onChange(ChangeEvent event)` - so, your method needs a `ChangeEvent` parameter and should look like this:

   ```
   @UiHandler("listBox")
   void whateverName(ChangeEvent event) {
       // ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Wow, that almost sounds like magic. I wouldn't have come up with the wildcard-kind of behaviour myself.

Comment: I'd recommend watching the GWT sessions from Google IO 2010 and 2009 (and even 2008) - GWT team members show and explain some of that magic :)

Comment: Kilmer: Thanks for tip. I'll sure do that!

Comment: Thanks for this.  The documentation is lacking in this respect.  I like using the @UiHandler annotation as it really cleans up my presenters.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your problem is in your onModuleLoad method:

```
public void onModuleLoad() 
{       
    HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld("BOTAO"); 

    // Using this way @UiHandler will not work
    //Document.get().getBody().appendChild(helloWorld.getElement()); 

    // correct way
    RootPanel.get().add(helloWorld);  
}
```